# What is the solution for the following minimization problem?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, least-squares

Given vectors $\mathbb{y}, \mathbb{b} \in \mathbb C^n$, find

$$\arg\min_{x \in \mathbb R} ~ \| \mathbb{y} - \exp(-jx) \mathbb{b} \|^2$$

Any help in this regard will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the norm you are using ? And what is $x$ ?

Comment: $x$ is a scalar and I am using norm such that $\|\mathbb{b}\|=\mathbb{bb^T}$.

Comment: @nicomezi can you direct me to a reference where I can find a similar example.

Comment: $x$ is a complex or a real  ? And I do not know a reference about this problem, but it does not seem very hard.

Comment: @nicomezi $x$ is real. I also think it should not be hard. Further I think since the norm is always $\geq 0$ therefore the value of $x$ which minimizes the objective can be derived from the equation $\mathbb{y}=\exp(-jx)\mathbb{b}$. What do you say?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo who said that $\mathbb{b}\mathbb{b^T}$ is a matrix?

Comment: If $b$ is a complex vector, you would rather define $\|b\|=b^t\overline{b}$. With $\overline{b}$ the vector made of conjugated entries of $b$.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo you are right but I did not say they are column vectors.

Comment: I just said they are vectors. So it should be obvious from the context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewriting as a complex [QCQP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratically_constrained_quadratic_program) in $z \in \mathbb C$,

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \| \mathrm a \, z - \mathrm b \|_2^2\\ \text{subject to} & z^* z = 1\end{array}$$

where $\mathrm a, \mathrm b \in \mathbb C^n$ are given. Note that

$$\| \mathrm a \, z - \mathrm b \|_2^2 = \left( \mathrm a \, z - \mathrm b \right)^* \left( \mathrm a \, z - \mathrm b \right) = \| \mathrm a \|_2^2 \, \underbrace{|z|^2}_{=1} + \| \mathrm b \|_2^2 - \left( \mathrm b^* \mathrm a \, z + \mathrm a^* \mathrm b \, z^* \right)$$

Let $c := \mathrm a^* \mathrm b =: \langle \mathrm a, \mathrm b\rangle$. Hence,

$$\| \mathrm a \, z - \mathrm b \|_2^2 = \| \mathrm a \|_2^2 + \| \mathrm b \|_2^2 - \left( c^* z + c \, z^* \right) = \| \mathrm a \|_2^2 + \| \mathrm b \|_2^2 - 2 \Re \{ c^* z \}$$

which is minimal when $\Re \{ c^* z \}$ is maximal. Let $\theta := \arg(c)$. Thus, the **optimum** is at $z = e^{i\theta}$.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. But I have one query. We know that norm is always greater than equal to zero. Then the minimum value of the above norm is achieved when $z\mathbb{a}-\mathbb{b}=0$ and why cant we find the value of $z$ from this equality?

Comment: Because $\mathrm a z = \mathrm b$ produces $$z = \frac{\mathrm a^* \mathrm b}{\| \mathrm a \|_2^2}$$ which may not have unit magnitude.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Further I think $z=e^{-i \theta}$ instead of $z=e^{i \theta}$ Right?

Comment: No, because $\Re \{ c^* z \}  = \Re \{  |c| e^{-i\theta} e^{i \arg(z)} \} = |c| \cos(\arg(z) - \theta)$.