# How to show that following is a solution of the optimization problem?

Tags: optimization, vectors, vector-analysis

In one of the research paper there are two complex vectors $\mathbf{y}$ and $\mathbf{a}$ and there is a scalar $x$. It is shown that $$\|\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{a}\exp(jx)\|^2_2$$ is minimized over $x$ when $$\exp(-jx)=\frac{\mathbf{y}^\mathbb{H}\mathbf{a}}{|\mathbf{y}^\mathbb{H}\mathbf{a}|}.$$ I know that $$\|\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{a}\exp(jx)\|^2_2=\|\mathbf{y}\|^2+\|\mathbf{a}\|^2-2\mathrm{Re}\{\mathbf{ya}^\mathbb{H}\exp(jx)\}$$ and minimizing the above expression with respect to $x$ is equivalent to maximizing $$2\mathrm{Re}\{\mathbf{ya}^\mathbb{H}\exp(jx)\}$$ which is maximized when $x=-\arg(\mathbf{ya}^\mathbb{H})$. Now I do not know how this results in $$\exp(-jx)=\frac{\mathbf{y}^\mathbb{H}\mathbf{a}}{|\mathbf{y}^\mathbb{H}\mathbf{a}|}.$$ Any help in understanding this will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2815402/339790

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $\cdot^\mathbb{H}$ denotes the transpose and complex conjugate, you actually have
$$\|\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{a}\exp(jx)\|^2_2=
\|\mathbf{y}\|^2+\|\mathbf{a}\|^2-2\mathrm{Re}\{\mathbf{y}^\mathbb{H}\mathbf{a}\exp(jx)\}.$$

Then this is minimized when
$$
 -x = \arg(\mathbf{y}^\mathbb{H}\mathbf{a}).
$$

Then the claim follows using basic properties of complex numbers:

If we have
$\exp(-jx)=\frac{\mathbf{y}^\mathbb{H}\mathbf{a}}{|\mathbf{y}^\mathbb{H}\mathbf{a}|}$,
then, taking $\arg(\cdot)$, it follows that
$$
\arg({\mathbf{y}^\mathbb{H}\mathbf{a}})
=
\arg\left(\frac{\mathbf{y}^\mathbb{H}\mathbf{a}}{|\mathbf{y}^\mathbb{H}\mathbf{a}|}\right) \\
=
\arg(\exp(-jx))
= -x + 2\pi k.
$$
Without loss of generality we can consider $k=0$, so we get
$
 -x = \arg(\mathbf{y}^\mathbb{H}\mathbf{a}).
$

Comment: Many many thanks for your answer. Actually I do not understand what are those other things that lead to the second equation in my post. I will be very thankful to you if you provide the details to reach that result. Thank you.

Comment: In fact I should found a vector $z$ such that $$\mathbb{y^Haz}=|\mathbb{y^Ha}|$$ So the question is how to solve this equation for $z$?

Comment: i added some details